# Why are Samsung-Tools not working?

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung NP700Z5A-S0AUS laptop and I've installed Samsung-Tools. But when i go to run the following command to turn on the back lit keyboard i get the following error:

```
sudo echo 8 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
bash: /sys/class/leds/samsung::kbd_backlight/brightness: No such file or directory
```

and I can't get the backlights to turn on.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 64bit 3.2.0-38-generic

Comment: Is the kernel module loaded (have you rebooted after installation)? How exactly did you install it in the first place? And as the answer suggests, you're not elevating your privileges correctly. Instead use the pattern `echo something | sudo tee /some/path/to/file`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got almost the same laptop (UK version) and I'm on 12.10, and get a slightly different error with permission denied instead. For me the problem is the redirect which needs to happen as root instead of as you.

Try this instead:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 8 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness'
```